# Keras - sample_weights vs. sample_weight in model.fit?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am using Keras with a tensorflow backend to train some CNNs for semantic segmentation of biomedical images. I am trying to weight every pixel in my input images during training and believe I am doing so with the data generator I am passing to model.fit.

However, I am a little confused about the meaning of 'sample_weights' vs. 'sample_weight' in the [documentation for model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit).

- 'sample_weights' is the third optional output from your dataset or image generator - i.e. the output of the generator can either be the tuple (inputs, targets) or the tuple (inputs, targets, sample_weights). I believe this lets me create a mask that weights my samples pixel-by-pixels, but this isn't super clear from the documentation.
- 'sample_weight' is a separate field that seems to be pretty clearly defined as a weight you can give to every sample. If I understand, this would allow me to give more or less weight to particular images in my training set.

Do I have this right? Thanks.

Comment: Both of them refer to the set of weights that are used to weigh per-sample (in your case each sample is an image, so per-image) losses. You can provide this set of weights by either 1) explicitly passing it as `sample_weight` argument and not using `tf.dataset`, Python's generator, or `keras.utils.Sequence` as your `x`, or 2) use either of those three as your `x` but construct them to return a tuple of `(x, y, weight)` instead of just `(x, y)`, and not using `sample_weight` argument.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying! Can I run one more thing by you @bui? I constructed keras.utils.Sequence as my `x` and had it pass a tuple of `(x, y, weight)`. `weight`, however, has the same dimensionality as `y` - i.e. with a batch size of 20, my train_generator returns `y` with size `(20,320,320,1)` and `weight` with size `(20,320,320)`. Therefore, there is a 320x320 image of weights for each of the 20 images in my batch.. If 'weight' is sample_weight, shouldn't it be a sequence the same length as the number of samples in the batch? I'm confused why this didn't throw an error. Thanks

Comment: Theoretically, `weight` should only be a 1D or 2D tensor. However, if you examine the official TF model [implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/engine/compile_utils.py#L199), you'll see that it doesn't actually enforce those conditions when applying `weight` so it all comes down to whether the loss function can handle such `weight` shape. Check out the `sample_weight` argument in TF base [loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss) class.

Comment: That is, I think that your `weight` shape doesn't result in errors because, TF loss, by default, will reduce by 1 dimension so your loss should be of shape `(20,320,320)`, which coincidentally matches with your weight shape. However, if your output was of shape `(20,320,320)` instead of `(20,320,320,1)`, then the loss will be of shape `(20,320)`, in which case you should get an error. Just my guess, though. You can verify it.